# How to make a flip card working in IE using TweenMax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer, gsap

I have the following card flipper but when is in IE it will show the back face as front face but upside down. Any idea how to fix this?

Here is my JSFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/qnwtLbzs/5/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        TweenMax.set('#flipContainer, #testCard',{
        perspective:500
        });
    TweenMax.set($('#testCard'),{
        transformStyle:'preserve-3d'
        });
    TweenMax.set('#testCard div',{
        backfaceVisibility:'hidden'
        });
    TweenMax.set('#back',{
        rotationX:-180
        });

    var flipped=false;
    $('#testCard').click(function(){
        if(!flipped){
            TweenMax.to($(this),1,{
                rotationX:180,
                onComplete:function(){
                    flipped=true;
                    }
                });
        }
        else{
            TweenMax.to($(this),1,{
                rotationX:0,
                onComplete:function(){
                    flipped=false;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: 10 & 11 I've tried both

Answer (score 0):

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qnwtLbzs/13/)

rather than setting perspective on the parent container, set it on the moving divs i.e. #front and #back, using the transformPerspective GSAP property that works only with animated elems not their parents. Also the same divs should be rotated not the #testCard

```
tl.to("#back",1,{rotationX:0}).to("#front",1,{rotationX:180},0)
```

I've added some css like position:absolute in order these divs stack upon each other, not under each other. 
I hope this will work in your IE.